# Linux getgrent() results in "Segmentation fault"

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to print all of system's groups (Ubuntu 20.04):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <grp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   printf("Here are all of this system's groups:\n\n");

   struct group* grp;
   while ((grp = getgrent()) != NULL)
      puts(grp->gr_name);

   endgrent();
   
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I run the program with `sudo` and I get:

```
$ sudo ./program
Here are all of this system's groups:

Segmentation fault
```

Same error happens when working with `struct spwd`.

### Update

I updated the source with the `include` lines and I left out the `lib/*.c` part. When I compile this exact piece of code:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: [...]
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)

$ gcc -std=c17 main.c -o program
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:11:18: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getgrent’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   11 |    while ((grp = getgrent()) != NULL)
      |                  ^~~~~~~~
main.c:11:16: warning: assignment to ‘struct group *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   11 |    while ((grp = getgrent()) != NULL)
      |                ^
main.c:14:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘endgrent’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   14 |    endgrent();
      |    ^~~~~~~~
```

And When I run it:

```
$ ./program 
Here are all of this system's groups:

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

$ sudo ./program 
Here are all of this system's groups:

Segmentation fault
```

Now when I run VS Code debugger it works correctly. VS Code is configured according to [this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux).

Here's my `launch.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc-9 - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc-9 build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You should compile it with debugging enabled (`-g`) and then run it in a debugger (`gdb`) to  figure out exactly where it's crashing (what line).

Comment: @Wes Hardaker - OK I just tried the VS Code debugging and it worked! I don't know what I am doing wrong: `gcc -std=c17 main.c lib/*.c -o program`

Comment: Odd.  that makes it hard to figure out what's wrong then :-/  i suspect it is a bug but, I don't think it's in your code.

Comment: I tried it on WSL and it outputs fine. I just compiled it like `gcc main.c`, and ran `a.out` wihout sudo. I wonder if your `lib/*.c` is causing any issues. Would suggest building with defaults even if just for troubleshooting. And if still crashes manually run with `gdb program`.

Comment: `while ((grp = getgrent()) != NULL)` <<-- this should not happen if you include the correct headers (and if these are found) BTW the `-std=c17` is strange: it suppresses the inclusion of `<grp.h>` (and c17 is *very* strange)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the correct headers:

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <grp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   printf("Here are all of this system's groups:\n\n");

   struct group* grp;
   while ((grp = getgrent()) != NULL)
      puts(grp->gr_name);

   endgrent();

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

---

Update: `-std=c17` is strange, it fails to include `<grp.h>` . You probably need `std=gnu17`, which includes some gnu+posix stuff.

Comment: Correct headers are in use.

Comment: Well, it works here. Maybe the problem is in another part of the code you didn't show us?

Comment: Thank you for your time. It worked with VS Code debugging. But the compiled program does not work. Are you on Ubuntu 20.04 as well?

Comment: Yes, but using a sane native compiler instead of Microsofts *software product*.

Comment: VS Code is configured to [use GCC](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux) as well.

Comment: You probably have some installation problem (such as not configuring where the libraries are located, or how to invoke the linker)

Comment: Omitting the `-std=c17` or using `-std=gnu17` fixed the problem and warnings are gone.